# Power BI Desktop - A card that shows most recent invoice above $1Million

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create a card that shows the most recent invoice above $1Million. Right now, I have a card that shows the most recent invoice, but I cannot find a way to only display the most recent above $1million.

```
Most Recent Invoice = CALCULATE(max(table1[Invoice_Line_Amount_USD]), lastdate(table1[Invoice_Posting_Date]))
```

EDIT: let me rephrase my question(s)/

I am wanting to show a table that has today's invoice only displayed and everyday when it is refreshed it will either show the invoices that were posted that day only or it will be blank (no invoices posted). I am wanting to have a card that shows the current days highest invoice about $1million and another card that shows the sum of the number of invoices for the current day. Then, I am going to create an alert that will notify me when an invoice about $1million is posted. The reason why I would like to display the highest invoice for that day on one of the cards is because when I receive that email it will tell me the amount of the highest invoice for that day (before I only had the sum of all of the invoices, which sent me an alert with only that amount).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Most Recent Invoice GTE 1M USD = CALCULATE(
    lastdate(table1[Invoice_Posting_Date])
    , 
       Filter( table1, table1[Invoice_Line_Amount_USD] >= 1000000)
)
```

If `lastdate` is not working correctly, try 
      `Max ( table1[Invoice_Posting_Date])`

The formula I did was filter the table for our conditions, which is `>= 1M` and the use the data to get the last date.

Comment: I receive an error that says the max function only accepts a column reference as an argument

Comment: I still cannot get it to work. I received another error. Is it possible to instead take the sum of the number of invoices received today only and display it on the card?

Comment: Are u trying to get the date or amount? My formula gives the date.

Comment: either one would work. I could not get the amount to show so if it is easier to show the sum of the total number of invoices received today then I would go that route.

Answer (score 0):

I reworked and did it two ways

- Let us say you have data as [Table with Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AVSG.png)
- I created measures and calculated columns as [Table Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwdKk.png)

```html
Is Today = IF(Table1[Invoice_Posting_Date] = TODAY (), 1, 0 )

Invoice Line Amount USD - Today = CALCULATE( SUM(Table1[Invoice_Line_Amount_USD]), FILTER(Table1, [Is Today] = 1 ))

Count Is Today GTE 1M = SUM( Table1[Is Today] )

Count Is Today = COUNTROWS( FILTER(Table1, [Is Today] = 1 ))
```

- Overall output as 
  [Overall output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FqWg.png)

[using filters plus required measure approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af5z6.png)

Comment: This works great, but I am running into an issue when I try to stream the data again. I cannot use a calculated column for Is Today. It will have to be converted into a measure. Is there a way to turn this into a measure?